# how can i add privilege checkbox of custom addon for vendor in cs cart ?

Tags: cs-cart

By default addons access will restricted to vendor. If i'll give the privilege to particular vendor he will able to access that addons.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

/You need auth area firts/

```
$condition = '';
if (AREA != 'A') {
    $auth = $_SESSION['auth'];
    $condition = ' AND (' . fn_find_array_in_set($auth['usergroup_ids'], 'usergroup_ids', true) . ") AND status = 'A'";
}
```

return....

You can see example in APP/addons/attachments